# БД + сервер + серверное приложение. Как это связать?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, клиент-сервер

В целях изучения *Java* и сопутствующих технологий решил написать клиент-серверное приложение с базой данных.

Как должно работать:

- есть база данных
- есть серверное приложение, которое будет получать запросы от клиентов для выборки данных из базы данных и отсылать им, парсить данные в базу из `txt`-файлов или даже с страниц в интернете или эл.почты
- клиенты (десктопный, *Android*, простенький веб-интерфейс

Изучаю *SQL* и, в принципе, понимаю как создать базу данных в *MySQL*. Примерно понимаю как написать серверное приложение. Для изучения *Tomcat*, наверное, серверное приложение и база данных должны на нём крутиться.

Суть вопроса: как серверное приложение и базу данных разместить на *Tomcat'e*?

Я знаю, где у меня исходники и `*.classes` серверного приложения и не знаю, где сохраняется база данных, если я работаю через консоль *MySQL*.

Как все это запустить на моём *PC*  под *Windows 10 Pro*?

Comment: Покажите, что у Вас уже реализовано.

Comment: по-большому счёту ничего, я так себе планирую. Сейчас читаю HEAD FIRST SQL, чтобы познакомиться с БД. Через пару-тройку дней готов приступать к написанию кода. Ещё волнует вопрос как код БД коммитить на GitHab. IntellijIdea  у меня настроена, но я не представляю себе в ней писать код для БД

Comment: *серверное приложение и база данных должны на нём крутиться.* - не совсем так. Tomcat - это веб-сервер, он отвечает за передачу HTTP-запросов вашему приложению, это именно он слушает какой-то там порт и отсекает негодные запросы. Сама же база данных вертится на своем отдельном сервере, если только это не file-based / in-memory база данных, которая живет в конкретном файле или памяти JVM соответственно.

Comment: А вот это уже интереснее. Можете детальнее объяснить как это все должно выглядеть, если вы поняли мою задумку?

**Tomcat - это веб-сервер, он отвечает за передачу HTTP-запросов вашему приложению** - это означает, что клиент обращается с запросом к Tomcat, тот в свою очередь к серверному(веб?) приложению, которое обрабатывает запрос и извлекает необходимые данные с базы данных и отдает TOMCAT, который в свою очередь отправляет ответ клиентскому приложению?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Итак, в целях обучения можете сделать Rest сервис. 
Работать это будет примерно следующим образом:

1. Юзеры через клиент(Веб браузер например) отправляет get или post
   запрос на ваш сервер.
2. Сервер обрабатывает http запрос клиента и формирует запрос к БД.
3. Затем сервер отправляет ответ(response), например, в виде JSON.

Теперь о технологиях:
Rest сервис можно запросто сделать с помощью Spring (http://spring-projects.ru/guides/rest-service/)
Для связи с БД используйте JDBC(так же огромное количество русских уроков)

Все это крутится на Tomcat'e А интерфейс это уже отдельная тема.
Надеюсь, все доступно объяснил, если есть вопросы, с радостью отвечу.

PS
Для подключения к БД используйте (Более подробно почитайте в гугле "JDBC mysql connection"):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
```

> Если клиенты отправляют запросы на сервер, то это отправляют Tomcat'y или серверному приложению, которое мне нужно написать?

Да, Tomcat'y, он следит за запросами(если можно так выразиться), а ваше приложение(сервер) их обрабатывает, выглядит это примерно так (если без спринга):

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         // Тут запросы к БД, и другая логика
    }
```

Этот фрагмент кода взят из реализации Сервлета, Если вы не знаете, что это очень рекомендую почитать, без сервлетов в j2ee никуда.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Что-то подобное я и хочу сделать. **Все это крутится на Tomcat'e** - вот это не знаю как реализовать. Если клиенты отправляют запросы на сервер, то это отправляют Tomcat'y или серверному приложению, которое мне нужно написать? Со Spring пока не знаком и не думаю, что охвачу это все вместе. Хотел сделать с помощью Hibernate, но тоже ещё рано, так как сначала нужно сделать ручками всё. Меня сейчас интересует где моя БД, которую я заполняю через консоль и как её и серверное приложение поставить на Tomcat. В интернетах пока не нашёл ответа.

Comment: Отлично! Теперь я понимаю, что ещё и с сервлетами нужно познакомиться, чтобы сложилась более полная картина что и к чему нужно прикрутить. А если вернуться к вопросу о БД. Вот второй день изучаю SQL и пишу в консоли MySQL. Где сохраняется эта БД? Как с ней работать из серверного приложения, которое должно обрабатывать клиентские запросы?

Comment: "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname" вот эту строку в getConnection надо заменить на jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDataBaseName, где MyDataBaseName - имя вашей базы данных, localhost значит, что сервер БД стоит на той же машине, а 3306 это порт с которым работает MySql

Comment: Для подключения базы данных уже с давних пор предлагается использовать ресурсы сервера приложений. Зачем этот вот DriverManager? Только лишь для ознакомления с основами JDBC? Но это не тот путь, который стоит использовать с tomcat и пр.

Comment: База сохраняется на сервере базы данных. И клиенту точное расположение файлов базы знать совершенно незачем, и не предусмотрено SQL такое знание. Для MySQL на Windows это может быть, например, папка C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data. Чем это может помочь даже не представляю.

Comment: Возможно это я чего-то не понимаю или выражаюсь неправильно. Допустим, я с консоли создал БД. А в серверном приложении я хочу к ней подключиться. Мне просто написать 'jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname' ?
Вчера читал о настройке Tomcat и, если правильно понял, то у него есть папка webapps, куда нужно положить серверную программу. А БД как? Если БД крутится на своём собственном сервере, то как мне их подружить? Я не понимаю этого.
С Java проще. У меня есть сорцы, у меня есть скомпилированный код, который я могу упаковать в *.jar и дальше использовать. А как с БД?

Comment: Да, действительно, БД находятся здесь **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data**
Как мне их загрузить в Tomcat, чтобы моя серверная программа могла с ними работать?

Answer (score 2):

Если достаточно хорошо знаете аглицкий для чтения мануалов, то лучше почитать документацию к tomcat, javaee.
На русском легко найти про java, про servlet-ы, про jdbc отдельно. А вместе не попадалось никогда.

Сначала подключение к БД описывается где-то в контексте tomcat-а. Есть варианты как именно, в какой файл записать эти строки (см. документацию):

```
<Context>
<!-- maxActive: Максимальное количество подключений в пуле. -->
<!-- maxIdle: Максимальное количество простаивающих подключений в пуле. -->
<!-- maxWait: Максимальное время ожидания подключения. -->
<!-- username and password: MySQL username and password for database connections  -->
<!-- driverClassName: Имя класса JDBC-драйвера. -->
<!-- url: JDBC connection url для подключения к базе. -->

  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="user" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

</Context>
```

Обратите внимание на url. Правильно догадались, что надо прописать `jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname`
Считайте, что url и есть база данных. Это адрес сервера (hostname:port) и имя базы, которое дали ей при созданий. Там она и хранится.
Вполне возможно и у tomcat-а есть web-морда, в которой можно создать такое подключение, вместо ручного написания xml. Не знаю. У других серверов есть такая возможность.

Потом в `WEB-INF/web.xml` web-приложения помещается ссылка на этот ресурс:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Наконец, используя аннотацию `@Resource`, внедряем базу например в servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HTTPServlet {
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/TestDB")
    private DataSource testDS;
    ...
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection conn = testDS.getConnection();
        ...
    }
}
```

Несмотря на обратный порядок изложения, имя ресурса (`@Resource(name)`) задаётся в программе и это имя с помощью конфигурации связывается с настоящей базой.

Возможно не всё тут правда, но как-то так.
Да... Длинновато получается. Но ничего не поделаешь - разработчику для tomcat-ов всяких надо знать все эти конфигурации (называются дескрипторы развёртывания или deployment descriptor) стандартные из javaee и специфические для конкретного сервера приложений. Зато подключение к базе задаётся не железно в коде, а гибко в конфигурации. Да и кода уже никакого нет, так - одна аннотация. Более-менее приличные IDE иногда упрощают написание этой конфигурации.

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное! Теперь до меня дошло!!! Да, БД крутится на сервере, локальном или удаленном. И подключается мы к ней с помощью "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname" А осенило меня случайно, прочитав одно предложение на msdn как работать с SQL Server с помощью JDBC.